# MariaDB 10.2 Performance Tuning - Lock wait timeout Issues

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-performance, database-deadlocks, my.cnf

I have 4 instance database-clustering (2 of them are mariadb 10.2 server and 2 of them is garbd server)
We use update-heavy queries in our databases, dealing with a huge tables which some of the tables have over 20 million records. Also we have lots of java application which use database and these threads mostly make "update" processes in tables. In the peak_time we use about 200 threads.

Our problem is that we have "Deadlock" in our applications. I believe that I can figure out by making some performance tuning in database configurations. My last configuration is below;

DB1: x.x.x.x

DB2: y.y.y.y

Garbd-1: w.w.w.w

Garbd-2: z.z.z.z

DB-1 : my.cnf

```
[client-server]

socket=/app/mysql/mysql.sock

port=3306

[mysqld]

user=mysql

port=3306

bind-address=0.0.0.0

socket=/app/mysql/mysql.sock

skip-name-resolve

lower_case_table_names=1

server-id=1

event-scheduler=ON

datadir=/app/mysql

pid-file=/app/mysql/db1.pid

log-error=/app/mysql/db1.err

log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

query_cache_type=0 

query_cache_size=0

#query_cache_limit = 4M

default_table_type = InnoDB

table_open_cache = 4096

open_files_limit = 8192

max_connections = 800

wait_timeout=100

interactive_timeout=100

#net_read_timeout=3600

#net_write_timeout=3600

max_heap_table_size=64M

tmp_table_size=64M

thread_cache_size=256

sort_buffer_size = 2M

join_buffer_size = 256K

read_buffer_size=128K

read_rnd_buffer_size = 256M

transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED

log_warnings

slow_query_log

long_query_time=5

# Physical RAM is 32G (8-core)

innodb_buffer_pool_size =24G

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=6

key_buffer_size=512M

nnodb_write_io_threads=8

innodb_read_io_threads=8

innodb_thread_concurrency = 16

#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:1G:autoextend

#innodb_autoextend_increment=128M

#innodb_file_per_table

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

#sync_binlog=1

innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M

innodb_log_file_size = 2G

innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 80

innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120

binlog_format=ROW

innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2

[mysqldump]

quick

max_allowed_packet = 512M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[mysqld_safe]

datadir=/app/mysql

pid-file=/app/mysql/db1.pid

log-error=/app/mysql/db1.err

[mariadb-10.2]

wsrep_on=ON

wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so

wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=10G;gmcast.listen_addr=tcp://0.0.0.0:4567;socket.checksum=2"

wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.92.221.215,10.92.221.216,10.92.223.215,10.92.223.216"

wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'

wsrep_node_address='10.92.221.215'

wsrep_node_name='ivrocsdbp00'

wsrep_sst_method=rsync

wsrep_sst_auth=sst_user:dbpass
```

These are also configured in second server, too with a server-id=2 and db2.pid, db2.err changes.

Is these changes might solve my problem?

I want to know that these parameters are well-configured ?

We have 32 GB RAM (8-core) in the servers.

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: To discuss deadlocks and lock-wait-timeout, we need to see the conflicting transactions, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Additional information request from DB-1. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `nnodb_write_io_threads` is a typo as mysqld wouldn't start with it.

I would start with `innodb_thread_concurrency = 0` to de-restrict the thread concurrency throttling.

Are your UPDATEs running fully indexed, ideally with PK in the WHERE?

Is there a good reason you have innodb_file_per_table commented out?

It might be worth verifying that your `table_open_cache` isn't too small (look at the process list and see if you regularly see queries in state of "opening|closing tables".

Are these servers VMs, and are they on a busy/overbooked host? I have seen very interesting spurious deadlocks in situations where clock ticks are unstable and unpredictable, e.g. on heavily overbooked virtual machines. There is some interesting thread racing happening under those conditions that seems to be completely un-reproducible on bare metal. Bumping up the instance size in the cloud environment usually cures the problem because bigger instances tend to be on less overbooked hosts.